# Pedir dos números y que nos diga cuál es el mayor, el menor y si son iguales

Tags: javascript

Quiero escribir un programa que pida dos números y nos diga cuál es el mayor, el menor y si son iguales.
Además si lo que ingresa el usuario no son números o ingresa números menores o iguales a cero, el programa debe volver a pedirlos.
Esto es lo que he escrito:

```javascript
let comprobar = true;

while (comprobar == true) {
    let num1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero"));
    let num2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un segundo numero"));

    if (num1 > 0 && num2 > 0) {
        comprobar = false;
        alert("Bien hecho");
    } else {
        comprobar = true;
        alert("Ingrese un NUMERO mayor que 0");
    }

    if (num1 > num2 && comprobar == false) {
        alert("El numero mayor es: " + num1);
    } else if (num1 == num2) {
        alert("Los numeros son iguales");
    } else {
        alert("El numero mayor es: " + num2);
    }
}
```

El código anda bien;
sin embargo, cuando ingreso un número menor o igual a 0 no debería mostrarme cuál es el mayor y el menor ya que puse `comprobar = false`.
Ocurre de igual modo si ingreso, por ejemplo, una letra.

Comment: Es sencillamente cambiar las condiciones... Incluso probalo _en papel_ (hacé la lógica en puño y letra, y testealo con ciertos valores). Pensalo, y escribilo :)

Comment: gracias, lo estuve viendo mas a profundidad y al final si funciono jsjs

Comment: Yo colocaría ese código dentro de un while con numero ingresado > 0, mientras el valor ingresado sea 0 o negativo que vuelva a pedirle al usuario que ingrese otro valor hasta que se cumpla la condición.

Answer (score 1):

Te iría mejor si cambias la lógica del ciclo a un ciclo infinito que se rompe cuándo los datos han sido bien ingresados y vuelve al inicio del ciclo cuando no.

Para ello utilizaremos las sentencias:

- `continue`, provoca que se vuelva al inicio del ciclo cuando se ejecuta. El ciclo evaluará sus condiciones antes de volver a ejecutarse.
- `break`, provoca que el ciclo termine incondicionalmente cuando se ejecuta.

De esta manera, podemos hacer un ciclo infinito `while (true)`, de manera que tenemos garantizado que siempre que se volverá a ejecutar al volver a este punto.

Luego, realizar las validaciones del caso, y si no se cumplen, ejecutar `continue`. He dejado dos validaciones:

La primera, una usando `isNaN`, ya que si no se ingresa un número sino una letra o una cadena alfanumérica `ParseInt` deja el valor `NaN` (*Not a Number*) en las variables. Si alguna de las dos es `NaN` mostramos un mensaje de error y volvemos al inicio.

La segunda validando que ambos sean enteros positivos, con la misma lógica.

Si pasa de este punto, solo falta comprobar e informar si hay alguno mayor o son iguales, y finalmente, utilizar `break` para romper el ciclo y salir.

```js
while (true) {
    let num1 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un numero"));
    let num2 = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese un segundo numero"));
    
    if (isNaN(num1) || isNaN(num2)) {
      alert("debe ingresar números");
      continue;
    }
    
    if (num1 <= 0 || num2 <= 0) {
      alert("debe ingresar números positivos (mayores a 0)");
      continue;
    }


    if (num1 > num2) {
        alert("El número mayor es: " + num1);
    } else if (num1 == num2) {
        alert("Los números son iguales");
    } else {
        alert("El número mayor es: " + num2);
    }
    break;
}
```

Puedes probar aquí mismo el funcionamiento presionando el botón *Ejecutar*.

Comment: 100% funcional. Faltaría agregarle al botón de cancelar un break de salida total del algoritmo.

Comment: Claro, si quiere hacerlo, ese ejercicio queda para el AP, la idea no es hacerle la tarea, sino ir dándole las herramientas para ayudarle a construir la lógica de programación e ir conociendo las herramientas a su disposición y el código publicado cumple con las especificaciones de la pregunta, que ya es bastante. :)

Comment: Claro la idea es que el aplique lo explicado, solo lo comentaba para que no obvie esos detalles que son buenas practicas.